# Algorithm or API for finding suitable alternative, abbreviation, or shorthand for word

Tags: algorithm, api, cpu-word, linguistics

We would like to produce a suitable abbreviation or shorthand for a given word. For instance, if someone gave us "picture", we would produce "pix" or if someone gave "ticket", we would produce "tix".

Are there any APIs or algorithms that can help with this? We know of Wordnik, but it doesn't offer exactly what we're looking for.

The best option at the moment is manually compiling a dictionary. That doesn't seem so hot.

Comment: You think you said it best yourself: "The best option at the moment is manually compiling a dictionary." I've never heard of either pix or tix, I would have used "pics" but I've never abbreviated "ticket". Different people most likely use different abbreviations, making a manual dictionary the preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a semi-automatic way: retrieve all abbreviations programmatically via API(e.g. Wordnik's API), then manually edit the result set to suit your need.